# (firestore) I want to retrieve the array information of a document as a list

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

The following information is stored in the firestore. 
I want to see the index of add_day as a list.

[image]
I wrote the following code, but only the most recent information appears in the list, I want to see the information of all the arrays of add_day.

---

This is ListActivity

```
public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private DayFragment dayFragment;
    private FragmentTransaction transaction;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        dayFragment = new DayFragment();
        transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.container, dayFragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }

    public void clickHandler(View view)
    {
        transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        switch(view.getId())
        {
            case R.id.btn_fragmentB:
                transaction.replace(R.id.container, dayFragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

DayFragment

```
public class DayFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "DayFragment";

    public DayFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.medicin_list_item, container, false);
        //final ImageView profileImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.profileImageView);
        final TextView name_medicin = view.findViewById(R.id.name_medicin_text);
         ......

        DocumentReference documentReference = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("medicinday").document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail());
        documentReference.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                    if (document != null)
                    {
                        if (document.exists())
                        {
                            List list = (List) document.getData().get("add_day");
                            for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++) {
                                Log.i("TEST", "data[" + i + "] > " + list.get(i).toString());
                                HashMap map = (HashMap) list.get(i);
                                name_medicin.setText(map.get("day").toString());
                                ....
                            }
                        }else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });
          return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you also might be interested in this article **[How to map an array of objects from Cloud Firestore to a List of objects?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-map-an-array-of-objects-from-cloud-firestore-to-a-list-of-objects-122e579eae10)**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show all the information in a single text view:

```
String msg = "";
List list = (List) document.getData().get("add_day");
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++) {
    Log.i("TEST", "data[" + i + "] > " + list.get(i).toString());
    HashMap map = (HashMap) list.get(i);
    msg = msg + map.get("day").toString() + "\n";
}
name_medicin.setText(msg);
```

Comment: I didn't understand. I would like to implement a list so that 6 kinds of information are listed in index 0 and index 1 of add day. I will use listview or recyclerview to list the list....

Comment: Currently, only the information of index 0 is displayed in the list.

Comment: With my code you should see all days in your text view. If you want to show them in a recycler view, you'll need to set up a recycler view and adapter for that. Instead of starting from scratch with explaining that here, I'd recommend following: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview or one of the many tutorials about that.